# String vs. Object type Constructor

Tags: java

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConTest conTest = new ConTest(null);

    }
```

POJO :

```
public class ConTest {

    private String  a;

    private Object  b;

    public ConTest(Object b) {
        System.out.println("Object" + b);
    }

    public ConTest(String a) {
        System.out.println("String :" + a);
    }

}
```

When I run this piece of code it always call constructor having `String` argument. Why?

Comment: To call the object version, you may cast the parameter : `new ConTest((Object)null);`

Comment: Yes your code is working fine if I want to call object's constructor. As far as I know object is a super class for all. So it should call object constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`null` can be passed to both constructors.

However, a `String` argument is more specific than an `Object` argument (since `String` is a sub-class of `Object`), and the method overloading resolution process prefers the method (or constructor in your case) with the more specific argument types.

As mentioned in the comments, if you want to force calling the constructor that accepts an `Object`, you can cast the `null` to `Object` :

```
ConTest conTest = new ConTest((Object)null);
```

Comment: Thanks for such a great explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The cause of this is, that there are multiple fitting methods (constructor in this case) that do fit the call. If there is more then one fitting method for a method call it allways takes the most specific one. In this case, `String` is more specific then `Object`. 
This can be seen in the inheritance chain. `String` inherits from `Object`

If there are two equally specific methods, then your compiler will tell you so with the error message `The method method(parameter) is ambiguous for the type Class`. This can be seen in this example.

```
public class A { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // compiler complains with:
        // The method test(Object) is ambiguous for the type A
        test(null); 
    }

    static void test(Object o) {
        System.out.println("IN OBJECT");
    }

    static void test(A a) {
        System.out.println("IN A");
    }

    static void test(B b) {
        System.out.println("IN B");
    }

    class B {

    }
}
```

With a slight change, by letting `B` inherit from `A` the method `test(B)` is getting more specific, because `B` is more specific then `A`, and the compiler error message is gone.

```
public class A { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test(null);
    }

    static void test(Object o) {
        System.out.println("IN OBJECT");
    }

    static void test(A a) {
        System.out.println("IN A");
    }

    static void test(B b) {
        System.out.println("IN B");
    }

    class B extends A{

    }
}
```

Comment: I like your answer and explanation !

Comment: Thanks for such a great explanation.